# Why isn't my car showing a small fuel input?

Tags: fuel-system, diesel

I just used a fuel pump to add 3.8 liters of diesel to my car (£5) from a local Jet fuel station. However my car's analogue fuel guage hasn't moved in the slightest. I have added similar amounts before (from different stations) and seen a visible change in the gauge, but nothing this time.

This has happened once before at the same station but with a different car and according to local social media communities it has happened to others with small amounts too.

I confronted the clerk the last time this happened and again today and both times have been told that the pumps are fine and that the only place the fuel could have gone is in my tank.

Is it possible the pumps don't pump anything or less than they should for the first few liters? Is there a minimum for my car to show a reading?

Car details:
2009 Peugoet 308, 1.6 HDI (diesel)
Fuel tank: 55 liters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those analogue gauges are notoriously inaccurate, and the level sensor may just have moved but only on the same winding as the tank may be quite wide so the vertical movement may only be 1cm or 2...,

I have seen the guys check the pumps for delivery and they have calibrated containers with temperature correction factors as the fuel is cold when coming from the underground tanks...

Comment: Thanks for your response! I added a further £20 of diesel (~15 liters) this morning from a trusted supermarket station and on starting the engine the gauge initially moved to where I expected it to be with only that 15L in the tank (as if the 3.8L from yesterday wasn't there) but after 5 seconds the gauge suddenly jumped a bit higher, which experience tells me was about equal to £5 worth of diesel. So it appears to have gone in, but didn't show on the gauge and still took a while to take affect when filled further. Strange behavior indeed, I'll have to get used to it!